# Error running sample web service code from weather.gov

Tags: php, webservice-client

I'm trying to integrate weather data from the NOAA in my web site, and as a starting point I was trying to run their sample code (available [here](http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/sample_products/ndfdXML.tar). The specific sample I'm trying to work with is the Basic Client sample (starting point is ndfdXML.htm).

I've followed the readme instructions for downloading nuSOAP and changing location to local paths, and changing the location of soapclient to www.weather.gov instead of localhost, but I'm still getting an error when I actually submit the page.

The error only shows up when I do a view-source, and this is what it says:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: 
[WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLserver.php': 
Extra content at the end of the document  in /opt/lampp/htdocs/weather/ndfdXMLclient.php:179

Stack trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/weather/ndfdXMLclient.php(179): SoapClient-&gt;SoapClient('http://www.weat...')
#1 {main}   thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/weather/ndfdXMLclient.php on line 179
```

Any idea what this means? I've been unable to find any kind of help offered by the actual weather service.

Comment: I can't post the entire sample; there are two files each having close to 1000 lines of code. That's why I posted the link to where the sample files are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you need to put the actual path to the wsdl in your SoapClient code.

http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLserver.php?wsdl

(note the "?wsdl" at the end)

It looks like your code is trying to create the SoapClient using http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLserver.php as the path for the wsdl.  If you actually go there, you can see that this isn't the wsdl.  It is actually located at the first url in this post.

Comment: Thanks; I tried that but now get a different error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function (&quot;getError&quot;) is not a valid method for this service in /opt/lampp/htdocs/weather/ndfdXMLclient.php:181
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: SoapClient-&gt;__call('getError', Array)
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/weather/ndfdXMLclient.php(181): SoapClient-&gt;getError()
#2 {main} (where line 181 is $err = $soapclient->getError();)

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what it needed. (Hm. By the time I submitted the comment, the comment I was replying to was gone. In any case, adding a second param of true to the instantiation of soapclient worked.)

Comment: Yeah I deleted the comment because I thought it would be better for me to test it and know it worked before recommending that you try it.  In any case I'm glad it's working for you!